# How I can move AvalonDock pane to the right side?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro, avalondock

I found 2 strange things:

1. Almost all examples of AvalonDock is outdated. There is now AvalonDock2 in NuGet anymore, only Xceed.Avalon - this is the same library? Many of examples doesn't work for "xceed-version".
2. What is more important, I can't do one simple thing: move pane panel from left-side (default state) to the right side. Of course, I can do it by mouse, but how is possible define startup location of xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup  as right-side? The code:

   ```
   <xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager" Grid.Row="1">
   <xcad:LayoutRoot>
       <xcad:LayoutPanel >
           <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="200" >
               <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                   <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Explorer" >

                   </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
               </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
           </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
       </xcad:LayoutPanel>
   </xcad:LayoutRoot>
   </xcad:DockingManager>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I just started AvalonDock a few weeks ago and i was wondering the same things.

I believe AvalonDock is the same library in Xceed, it is true that some examples are outdated, but if you dig enough, you can find some useful stuff.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483507/AvalonDock-Tutorial-Part-Adding-a-Tool-Windo it helped me a lot.

Regarding your question, how do you want to move it to the right? Are you talking about the header, or all the tab?

Comment: I solved the issue. If you using Visual Studio then you remember Solution Explorer panel (in my VS it is in right-side), most part of screen - this is opened file. When I tried implement something like this, panel (like "Solution Explorer") always appeared in left side. That was this code:

<xcad:LayoutRoot>
  <xcad:LayoutPanel>
    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="350">
    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane />

It simple: just swap last two lines. We see panels in order of declaration, from left to right!